# Whitelisting target="_blank" with regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I'm working on a site that sanitizes output from the database so that some html tags are allowed. It's using Regex to sanitize the data.

At the moment it allows standard 
    [Google](http://www.google.com) (standard href with no target)
but does not allow

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" title="Google">Google</a>
```

The code looks like this at the moment:

```
private static Regex _tags = new Regex("<[^>]*(>|$)",
RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.Compiled);
private static Regex _whitelist = new Regex(@"
^</?(b(lockquote)?|code|d(d|t|l|el)|em|h(1|2|3)|i|kbd|u|li|ol|p(re)?|s(ub|up|trong|trike)?|ul)>$|
^<(b|h)r\s?/?>$",
    RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
private static Regex _whitelist_a = new Regex(@"
^<a\s
href=""(\#\d+|(https?|ftp)://[-a-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;\(\)]+)""
(\stitle=""[^""<>]+"")?\s?>$|
^</a>$",
    RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
private static Regex _whitelist_img = new Regex(@"
^<img\s
src=""https?://[-a-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;\(\)]+""
(\swidth=""\d{1,3}"")?
(\sheight=""\d{1,3}"")?
(\salt=""[^""<>]*"")?
(\stitle=""[^""<>]*"")?
\s?/?>$",
    RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);


/// <summary>
/// sanitize any potentially dangerous tags from the provided raw HTML input using 
/// a whitelist based approach, leaving the "safe" HTML tags
/// CODESNIPPET:4100A61A-1711-4366-B0B0-144D1179A937
/// </summary>
public static string Sanitize(string html)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(html)) return html;

    string tagname;
    Match tag;

    // match every HTML tag in the input
    MatchCollection tags = _tags.Matches(html);
    for (int i = tags.Count - 1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        tag = tags[i];
        tagname = tag.Value.ToLowerInvariant();

        if (!(_whitelist.IsMatch(tagname) || _whitelist_a.IsMatch(tagname) || _whitelist_img.IsMatch(tagname)))
        {
            html = html.Remove(tag.Index, tag.Length);

        }
    }

    return html;
}
```

I'd like to allow hrefs with targets aswell.

Any help with this would be great, thanks.

Comment: Regexes are not appropriate for this purpose. You need to use a HTML parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edited to include second request in comment.

Change:

```
private static Regex _whitelist_a = new Regex(@"
^<a\s
href=""(\#\d+|(https?|ftp)://[-a-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;\(\)]+)""
(\stitle=""[^""<>]+"")?\s?>$|
^</a>$",
RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

to:

```
private static Regex _whitelist_a = new Regex(@"
^<a(\starget=""[^""<>]+"")?\s
href=""(\#\d+|(https?|ftp)://[-a-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;\(\)]+)""
(\starget=""[^""<>]+"")?(\stitle=""[^""<>]+"")?\s?>$|
^</a>$",
RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

It's not necessarily the perfect solution, but this will allow a "target" both before and after the "href", or before, or after, or not at all.

You should be able to create a regex that is much more succinct, similar to this:

```
^<a(\s+(?:target|href|title)="[^"<>]+")*\s*>$|^</a>$
```

But I don't know exactly how you would write this in your code, as I'm not familiar with C# or .Net. But you could try the following:

```
private static Regex _whitelist_a = new Regex(
    @"^<a(\s+(?:target|href|title)=""[^""<>]+"")*\s*>$|^</a>$",
    RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
);
```

The advantage of this solution over the above solutions is that it will allow any of `href`, `target` and `title` in any order, and with any number of spaces in between them.

Comment: Hi, this is working, thanks, however it is also possible for the user to enter <a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com" title="Google">Google</a> as well as <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" title="Google">Google</a> (which now works) is it possible to add a rule for this? Thanks

Comment: Something like this would add more whitespace support and use of " and ' for quoting... 
private static Regex reWhitelistA = new Regex(
 @"^<a(\s+(?:target|href|title)\s*=\s*(""[^""<>]*""|'[^'<>]*'))*\s*>$|^</a>$",
   RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.Compiled);